# Forçar container > row > col ser não-responsivel no Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3, layout-responsivo

Tenho a seguinte family tree: https://codepen.io/chuongdang/pen/lcnsC

É possível perceber que a responsividade de um framily tree não existe. Para se ter uma boa visibilidade dessa tree, a melhor forma seria fazer o `container > row > col` onde encontra-se essa tree ser não-responsivel, tendo um scroll horizontal, forçando ficar não responsivo só nessa div.

A `<div class="tree">` encontra-se dentro de um `container > row > col-12`.

Como fazer isso no Bootstrap 3.3.7?

Answer (score 0):

De maneira nativa, não há. O que fiz para ter este comportamento é:

1. Adicionei `width: 9999px` e `overflow: auto` na classe `.tree`. Assim, temos certeza que a tree não irá ficar quebrada por causa de responsividade;
2. Depois, via Java Script peguei a `largura` total efetiva da tree e armazenei em `largura`;
3. Apliquei a `largura` obtida no `ul` da `.tree` com + 10 por causa do `padding left` e `right`;
4. Removi a largura `9999px` do container da class `.tree`, fazendo assim o `overflow` ter efeito e criar a rolagem;

```js
$(function() {
  var largura = $('.tree > ul > li').width();
  $('.tree > ul').width(largura + 10);
  $('.tree').width('auto');
});
```

```css
/*Now the CSS*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.tree {
  display: block;
  width: 9999px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.tree ul {
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}


/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before,
.tree li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}


/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/

.tree li:only-child::after,
.tree li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}


/*Remove space from the top of single children*/

.tree li:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}


/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/

.tree li:first-child::before,
.tree li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}


/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/

.tree li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}


/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/

.tree ul ul::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li a {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}


/*Time for some hover effects*/


/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/

.tree li a:hover,
.tree li a:hover+ul li a {
  background: #c8e4f8;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}


/*Connector styles on hover*/

.tree li a:hover+ul li::after,
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before,
.tree li a:hover+ul::before,
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before {
  border-color: #94a0b4;
}


/*Thats all. I hope you enjoyed it.
Thanks :)*/
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--
We will create a family tree using just CSS(3)
The markup will be simple nested lists
-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1>Título</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">

      <div class="tree">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Parent</a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Child</a>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Child</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <p>texto</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```